# Is there a way to cache Jsoup get request?

Tags: android, caching, get, jsoup

I make the same request at different point in my app

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.sampleURL.com")
                                .get();
```

Is there a way to cache the get request?

Comment: You can save the HTML into a file and read it wherever you want.

Comment: Cache where? You can simply keep `doc` in memory until you need it again, or save it to whatever local storage is available to your app.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin yes, thought about it too. was looking if it was possible more transparently. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass Cache-Control=cache in header to cache GET request

Answer (score 0):

Get the [cache directory](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#internal-remove-cache) from a `Context`. With Hilt, you can use the application context. To get the html of the page as a string, use `doc.outerHtml()`.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object ApiModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideHtmlRepository(
        app: Application
    ) = HtmlRepository(app)
}
```

```
class HtmlRepository(
    context: Context
) {
    private val cacheDir = context.cacheDir
    
    init {
        val storageManager = context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE) as StorageManager
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val cacheDirUuid = storageManager.getUuidForPath(cacheDir)
            val quota = storageManager.getCacheQuotaBytes(cacheDirUuid)
            Log.d("CACHE", "quota: $quota $cacheDirUuid")
        }
        Log.d("CACHE", "cache directory: ${context.cacheDir}")
    }

    suspend fun loadHtml(url: String): Document = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val cacheFile = cacheFile(url)
        if (cacheFile.exists()) {
            Jsoup.parse(cacheFile, "UTF-8", url)
        } else {
            Jsoup.connect(url).get()
                .also { doc -> cache(doc.outerHtml(), url)}
        }
    }

    private suspend fun cache(html: String, url: String) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        // launch new coroutine to avoid waiting
        launch {
            val cacheFile = cacheFile(url)
            FileOutputStream(cacheFile).use { stream ->
                stream.write(html.toByteArray())
            }
        }
    }

    private fun cacheFile(url: String): File {
        val encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(url, Charsets.UTF_8.name()).htmlEncode()
        return File(cacheDir, "$encodedUrl.html")
    }
}
```